# Chef templates being executed before provider (ark)

Tags: chef-infra

I'm developing a cookbook where the ark provider is being used and a few other template files.

My main problem is that the template file is created before the ark is executed... therefore the directory where the file should be put doesn't exist when the recipe is executed.

How do I execute the templates only after ark is completed ?

Below is the code of the recipe:

```
version = node['tomcat']['version']
major_version = version[0]
download_url = "http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-#{major_version}/v#{version}/bin/apache-tomcat-#{version}.tar.gz"

user node['tomcat']['user'] do
    comment "Tomcat user"
    system true
    shell "/bin/false"
    home node['tomcat']['install_dir']
end

ark 'tomcat' do
    url download_url
    version version
    prefix_root node['tomcat']['install_dir']
    home_dir node['tomcat']['install_dir'] + "/tomcat"
    owner node['tomcat']['user']
end

template '/etc/init.d/tomcat' do
    source "tomcat.init.redhat.erb"
    owner "root"
    group "root"
    mode "0774"
    variables(:name => major_version)
end

service 'tomcat' do
  supports :restart => true, :reload => true, :status => true
  action [:enable, :start]
end

template node['tomcat']['install_dir'] + "/tomcat/conf/default" do
    source "default.erb"
    owner node['tomcat']['user']
    group node['tomcat']['user']
    mode "0644"
    variables(:tomcat => node['tomcat'].to_hash)
    notifies :restart, "service[tomcat]"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you notify tomcat to restart.

```
ark 'tomcat' do
  # ...
  notifies :create, 'template[/etc/init.d/tomcat]', :immediately
end
```

And then make sure you add `action :nothing` to your template resource inline.

Comment: I guess the talk is about `template node['tomcat']['install_dir'] + "/tomcat/conf/default"`, not `template '/etc/init.d/tomcat'`. because the latter does not actually depend on anything. The problem, I think is that ark creates `node['tomcat']['install_dir'] + "/tomcat"` folder but not `.../tomcat/conf`

Comment: indeed the problem was on the second template (sorry for not being clear). your suggestion worked perfectly... I had the wrong impression that I needed to set ark to `action :nothing` and not the templates (don't ask me why I understood that way...it now makes sense after your input @sethvargo)

Comment: I have the same problem, but it used to work with an earlier version of the ark cookbook (0.0.17). Has this changed in the behaviour of the ark cookbook?

Comment: Cookbooks follow semantic versioning, so it is likely that the API has changed in versions post 0.1.0